# Append ellement to list, err list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to analyse the Brightkite network and its [checkins](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/loc-brightkite.html). basically I have to count the number of distinct users who checked-in at each location. I just When I run this piece of code on small file (just cut 300 first lines from original file) it works good. But if I try to do the same with original file. I get the error

```
users.append(columns[4])
IndexError: list index out of range. What it could be
```

Here is my code:

```
from collections import Counter
f = open("b.txt")
locations = []
users = []
for line in f:
    columns = line.strip().split("\t")
    locations.append(columns[0])
    users.append(columns[4])
l = Counter(locations)
ml = l.most_common(10)
print ml
```

Here is structure of data

```
58186   2008-12-03T21:09:14Z    39.633321       -105.317215     ee8b88dea22411
58186   2008-11-30T22:30:12Z    39.633321       -105.317215     ee8b88dea22411
58186   2008-11-28T17:55:04Z    -13.158333      -72.531389      e6e86be2a22411
58186   2008-11-26T17:08:25Z    39.633321       -105.317215     ee8b88dea22411
58187   2008-08-14T21:23:55Z    41.257924       -95.938081      4c2af967eb5df8
58187   2008-08-14T07:09:38Z    41.257924       -95.938081      4c2af967eb5df8
58187   2008-08-14T07:08:59Z    41.295474       -95.999814      f3bb9560a2532e
58187   2008-08-14T06:54:21Z    41.295474       -95.999814      f3bb9560a2532e
58188   2010-04-06T06:45:19Z    46.521389       14.854444       ddaa40aaa22411
58188   2008-12-30T15:30:08Z    46.522621       14.849618       58e12bc0d67e11
58189   2009-04-08T07:36:46Z    46.554722       15.646667       ddaf9c4ea22411
58190   2009-04-08T07:01:28Z    46.421389       15.869722       dd793f96a22411
```

Comment: @ Can you post a couple of lines from your b.txt

Comment: 1st column is id ,second column  is it timestamp.3rd and 4th are??
Can you describe each column and also desired output?

Comment: @Ajay, I think the list names users and locations is a pretty good clue.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the csv module and update the counter as you go:

```
from collections import Counter

import csv

with open("Brightkite_totalCheckins.txt") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
    cn = Counter()
    users = []
    for row in r:
        # update Counter as you go, no need to build another list
        # locations is row[4] not row[0]
        cn[row[4]] += 1
        # same as columns[]
        users.append(row[0])
print(cn.most_common(10))
```

Output from the full file:

```
[('00000000000000000000000000000000', 254619), ('ee81ef22a22411ddb5e97f082c799f59', 17396), ('ede07eeea22411dda0ef53e233ec57ca', 16896), ('ee8b1d0ea22411ddb074dbd65f1665cf', 16687), ('ee78cc1ca22411dd9b3d576115a846a7', 14487), ('eefadd1aa22411ddb0fd7f1c9c809c0c', 12227), ('ecceeae0a22411dd831d5f56beef969a', 10731), ('ef45799ca22411dd9236df37bed1f662', 9648), ('d12e8e8aa22411dd90196fa5c210e3cc', 9283), ('ed58942aa22411dd96ff97a15c29d430', 8640)]
```

If you print the lines using repr you see the file is tab separated:

```
'7611\t2009-08-30T11:07:52Z\t53.6\t-2.55\td138ebbea22411ddbd3a4b5ab989b9d0\n'
'7611\t2009-08-30T00:15:20Z\t53.6\t-2.55\td138ebbea22411ddbd3a4b5ab989b9d0\n'
'7611\t2009-08-29T20:28:13Z\t53.6\t-2.55\td138ebbea22411ddbd3a4b5ab989b9d0\n'
'7611\t2009-08-29T15:53:59Z\t53.6\t-2.55\td138ebbea22411ddbd3a4b5ab989b9d0\n'
'7611\t2009-08-29T15:19:36Z\t53.6\t-2.55\td138ebbea22411ddbd3a4b5ab989b9d0\n'
'7611\t2009-08-29T15:16:45Z\t53.6\t-2.55\td138ebbea22411ddbd3a4b5ab989b9d0\n'
'7611\t2009-08-29T11:52:32Z\t53.6\t-2.55\td138ebbea22411ddbd3a4b5ab989b9d0\n'
..................
```

The very last line is:

```
 '58227\t2009-01-21T00:24:35Z\t33.833333\t35.833333\t9f6b83bca22411dd85460384f67fcdb0\n'
```

so make sure that matches and you have not modified the file and there will be no indexError.

You code fails because you have some lines that look like `'7573\t\t\t\t\n'`, the first of which is line number `1909858` so splitting and stripping leaves you with `['7573']`.
Using the csv file however gives you `['7573', '', '', '', '']`.

If you actually want a list of ten uniques locations, you need to find the values that are equal to `1`:

```
# generator expression of key/values where value == 1
unique = (tup for tup in cn.iteritems() if tup[1] == 1)

from itertools import islice

# take first 10 elements from unique
sli = list(islice(unique,10))
print(sli)

('2d4920e7273c755704c06f2201832d89', 1), ('a4ef963e84f83133484227465e2113e9', 1), ('474f93a6585111dea018003048c10834', 1), ('413754d668b411de9a19003048c0801e', 1), ('d115daaca22411ddb75a33290983eb13', 1), ('4bac110041ad11de8fca003048c0801e', 1), ('fc706c121ec1f54e0a828548ac5e26b8', 1), ('1bcd0cf0f0bd11ddb822003048c0801e', 1), ('e6ed6c09b8994ed125f3c5ef6c210844', 1), ('493ef9b049cfb2c6c24667a931f1592172074545', 1)]
```

To get the count of all unique locations we can use the rest of our generator expression with `sum` adding 1 for every element and add the total to the length of what we took with islice:

```
print(sum(1 for _ in unique) + len(sli))
```

Which gives you `426831` unique locations.

Using `re.split` or `str.split` is not going to work for an obvious reason:

```
In [13]: re.split("\s+", '7573\t\t\t\t\n'.rstrip())
Out[13]: ['7573']

In [14]:  '7573\t\t\t\t\n'.rstrip().split()
Out[14]: ['7573']
```

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't get complitly how you have done it. Why users is row[4] not row[0]. Actually at the end I need to count unique per user-locations, and choose 10 from them.

Comment: @AnnaPresnyakova, you had the logic backwards in your own code, users is the first column and location is the last

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in your data, I checked the website data you provided. The data is not actually separated by tab spaces. They are just separated by spaces. I added some lines to replace the spaces with tabs then splitted the line. It works now.

```
from collections import Counter
f = open("b.txt")
locations = []
users = []
for line in f:
    line = line.replace("   ","\t")
    line = line.replace("    ","\t")
    line = line.replace("       ","\t")
    line = line.replace("     ","\t")
    columns = line.strip().split("\t")
    locations.append(columns[0])
    users.append(columns[4])
l = Counter(locations)
ml = l.most_common(10)
print ml
```

Note : If you have errors like this check your data, the error message is clear that there is no 4th element.

I hope this is the error you want to resolve.

Comment: Nope. I checked the data you gave with the following code. If there are tab spaces in every line, then the array would have 4 elements.  f = open("b.txt")
for line in f:
 print line.split("\t")

Comment: I didn't check the number of spaces exactly in the data you added now. You can count then and edit the above code of mine.